# Tried to fix wholes in mesh, getting purple and no idea how to go on

Tags: mesh, sculpting, error

I'm a newbie and totally lost.

Started to sculpt my first little project. There was a rough edge that I couldn't get rid of so I deleted some points and tried to fill this up with selecting the edges and press F.

Now, in sculpt mode, there are some purple polygones and nothing works like it should.

Please heeeeelp... No Idea what I did but obviously it war a big mistake.

Is all of my hours of "sculpting" lost?

Thank you so much, if anybody can help me out of this...

Best regards, Rose[image]

Comment: “Holes” you mean. Hmm, well, the areas where the topology basically died will probably need to be cut out somehow, but I think this is salvageable.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object B that will be a kind of bandage. Give your head a *Boolean* modifier with this bandage as the boolean *Object*, choose the *Union* type of boolean:

[image]

Apply the *Boolean*, remove the original bandage, sculpt the head with the *Smooth* brush in order to merge the bandage with the head:

[image]

As for the colored area, these are face sets, it's a kind of mask, to paint face sets use this brush:

[image]

To remove, go into the *Face Sets* panel > *Face Set from Visibl*e:

[image]